# Water solubility of hydroxbenzoic acids

Tags: organic-chemistry

why is the log P of the esters lower than the alcohols?
Is it because of the formation of dimers?

[image]

Comment: Guess OH group is more water-friendly than ester, due to formation of hydrogen bonds. Indeed, look at a simpler pair: ethanol is infinitely soluble in water (in other words, _miscible_), while ethyl acetate is not.

Comment: But the logP values of the esters are lower than the alcohols!

Comment: Oops... Well, let's wait for someone to undo my explanation and provide a better one.

Comment: What is your source for the logP values?

Comment: Source is in brackets below.